# Read CSV file with some blank fields in R

Tags: r, csv

Below is the example of the csv file that I have:

```
A       B       C       D
Name    Score  Grade    Comments
Jane    55.5   A2
Peter                   Absent
May                     She is cool.
Joy            F
```

I would like to read this format of csv file (Shown in Excel with cells) in R. The actual csv file that I have include many more columns and rows.

I have tried read.csv function but I received error message: line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `na.strings=''` in the `read.csv`, also try with `fill=TRUE`

Comment: What you show there is not a CSV (note the missing commas). It looks like a fixed width file. Please clarify.

Comment: @akrun Hi, I have tried that, but still doesn't work

Comment: @Roland That's how it looks like when I open the csv file with cells. (Microsoft Excel)

Comment: Well, that's not useful. You need to show how it looks like in a text editor (e.g., notepad).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the separator character is the right one `sep=","` or `sep=";"` usually. You also have to check in in the excel properties. Also check if the first line is correctly formated in excel.